# Lost end of the string

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, networking

I have a problem, and I can not solve it for several days.
My simple code (dll file):

```
public static string RegisterUser(string table, string l, string p)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(login, password) VALUES ('" + l + "','" + p + "');";
    return query;
}
```

Everything works fine, but when I want to write the data received on the network, it does not return the full string, for example

```
string recieveStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(connection.Buffer); //received text: RegUser:nipercop:passwrd
string[] strArr = recieveStr.Split(':');
if (strArr[0].Equals("RegUser"))
{
    // string p = strArr[2]; //passwrd
    // sendStr = SqlCommands.RegisterUser("users",strArr[1], "passwrd");//works fine
    sendStr = SqlCommands.RegisterUser("users",strArr[1], strArr[2]); // doesn't work
 }
```

returns message like that:

```
INSERT INTO users(mail, password) VALUES ('nipercop','passwrd
```

Lost end of the string " ') ". No errors, no warnings, no anything.
I tried change encoding to ASCII on server, on client, but no effect.

Comment: strArr[2] gives you which value?

Comment: I agree with @AngryTiger, there is a chance your string contains something it shouldn't (i.e. might need `String.Trim()`ing. Also the example `RegisterUser()` method you posted takes 3 parameters, your example usage calls it using only 2 - is there another overloaded method?

Comment: Oh sorry guys, i corrected the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is was reading strings from the buffer.

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(connection.Buffer,0 , bufferLength);
```

Because the buffer length was (for example) 1024 bytes, and my last variable was length of the remainder of the length of the other variables, ie contained a empty symbols (spaces). Fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `string.Format`:

```
string.Format(@"INSERT INTO {0}(login, password) VALUES ('{1}','{2}');", table, l, p);
```

Though ideally you should be using [prepared SQL statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The reason being is any of the values you insert could contain unexpected values, which leaves your code vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and a plethora of other bad things.

For example if `strArr[2]` would contain `"` here, it'd cut off the query and result in an error. As it stands, your code doesn't account for that while seemingly accepting input from a remote socket. That's something you may want to revise.